# Strange loops and append functions within them

Tags: python

I a currently trying to understand the code of a python program which in essence is a pacman game. While I was reading the code I found a strange loop which seems to reset a list to "empty" followed by appending a value to this list. Here is what I mean:

```
def drawFood(self, foodMatrix ):
    foodImages = []    


    color = FOOD_COLOR 
    for xNum, x in enumerate(foodMatrix):                                                                   
        if self.capture and (xNum * 2) <= foodMatrix.width: color = TEAM_COLORS[0]   
        if self.capture and (xNum * 2) > foodMatrix.width: color = TEAM_COLORS[1]


        imageRow = []                                               
        foodImages.append(imageRow)                                                                          
        for yNum, cell in enumerate(x):                             
            if cell: # There's food here

                screen = self.to_screen((xNum, yNum ))                                                  

                dot = circle( screen,                                                                                 
                              FOOD_SIZE * self.gridSize,
                              outlineColor = color, fillColor = color,
                              width = 1)                                                                                
                imageRow.append(dot)                                                                                             
            else:
                imageRow.append(None)
    print('foodimages' + str(foodImages))            
    return foodImages
```

Although `foodImages = []` and `imageRow = []` are both reset to empty in every iteration of the loop, the foodImages list seems to continue growing.

Is it possible that the because we append dot to `imageRow` and `imageRow` to the list `foodImages` that the `foodImages` list continues to grow although `imageRow` was set to empty?

Comment: `imageRow` is reset on every iteration, but `foodImages` is not.

Comment: It would be more readable, if you add also few lines showing the call of `drawFood` and print e.g. size of the list you care about.

Comment: ... and when stuff is added to `imageRow`, it is indirectly added to `foodImages`, because `imageRow` is contained therein. It may be easier to understand (and semantically equivalent) if you move `foodimages.append(imageRow)` below the inner loop.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be a little confusing.

```
imageRow = []                                               
foodImages.append(imageRow) 
...
imageRow.append("something")
```

`foodImages` is only set to an empty list at the start.
Even though you add an empty `imageRow` to the `foodImages` here, you are still working on the same `imageRow` object later. So when you further down in the code add something to `imageRow` it will be reflected the `foodImages` list (which contains the `imageRow` object).

Answer (score -1):

Python seems to treat `list` not as `int` or `str`. See the example below. `list` is like reference or pointer in C programming language.

```
#example 1
>>> a = []
>>> x = 1
>>> a.append(x)
>>> a
[1]
>>> x = 2
>>> a
[1]

#example 2
>>> a = []
>>> x = "hoge"
>>> a.append(x)
>>> a
['hoge']
>>> x = "fuga"
>>> a
['hoge']

#example 3(your problem)
>>> a = []
>>> x = [1]
>>> a.append(x)
>>> a
[[1]]
>>> x[0] = 2
>>> a
[[2]]
```

Comment: every variable contains a pointer to an object in Python, it's just that `int` and `str` are immutable, so it *seems* that it's copied and stored in the variable directly.